# Does a sequence of $C^1$ functions converge to a $C^1$ function if the derivatives are bounded and equicontinuous?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, equicontinuity

My question is: If $f_n\to f$ pointwise in $(0,1)$ where $f_n\in C^1$ (continuously differentiable), AND the family $\{f_n'\}$ is uniformly bounded and equicontinuous, then is $f\in C^1$ as well? Ie, is $f$ also continuously differentiable?

My intuition tells me that $|f_n'(x)|\leq M$ and equicontinuity should be enough to force $f'(x)$ to exist and be continuous but I'm not sure where to start a rigorous proof.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: If the sequence $\{f'_n\}$ were uniformly convergent on $[0,1]$ you would be in luck.  If it had a uniformly convergent *subsequence* ...?  I think there are a couple of Italians who might help here.

Comment: How do you know the limit of the subsequence is the derivative of $f$?

Comment: This looks very similar https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4045355/42969.

Answer (score 5):

Since differentiabilty is a local property we might as well work within a closed interval contained in  $(0,1)$. Fix a point $c$ in this interval. We can apply Arzelà-Ascoli Theorem to find  a subsequence $(f_{n_k})$ which converges uniformly to some continuous function $g$.
Now $f_{n_k}(x)=f_{n_k}(c)+\int _c^{x} f_{n_k}'(t)dt$. Letting $k \to \infty$ we get $f(x)-f(c)=\int_c^{x} g(t)dt$. This implies that $f$ is continuously differentiable.

Comment: But why would $f_{n_k}'$ converge to $g$? I think you have a typo there.

Comment: Can't upvote with a misspelling:   Arzelà including the *accento grave* that indicates how our friend would have pronounced his name.  Good answer.

Comment: +1: Nice answer.

Comment: I see how we can use the fundamental theorem of calculus to see that $f'(x)=g(x)$ (I think this is the correct reasoning), but I still don't see where the boundedness assumption is used.

Comment: @zz20s  He needed the boundedness in order to apply the  Arzelà-Ascoli theorem.  IF you didn't learn that theorem then maybe you want a different method.

Comment: It is used to apply Arzela-Ascoli Theorem. Equi-continuity follows by MVT and boundeness of derivatives. @zz20s

Comment: @B.S.Thomson I did learn that theorem, the connection wasn't apparent until your hint and this excellent answer. Out of curiosity though, what would be another approach? Is there a way to do it merely with epsilon's and deltas?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: Is this different from https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4045376/42969 ?

Comment: One difference is the functions are given on $(0,1)$  and I don't think you can apply Arzela-Ascoli directly. @MartinR